# Nested While loop not counting two files correctly

Tags: java, while-loop, text-files, fileinputstream

I am working on a program that takes a file in from the command line. this file is then compared to a text file to see if it has certain words in it. if it does, i want it to increment a counter for each time that certain word is found.

I thought I was on the right track, using while loops to make the files go through to completion, and using contains to see if the words existed within both files.

However, when i output the number, it is just the total number of words in the text file! I'm not sure why this is. I am new to java so this is something i'm not too comfortable around haha, any help would be appreciated

```
String fname = args[0];      // input file of text
    String words1;
    String words2;
    int numWords = 0;            // total number of words
    

    FileInputStream fileKeywords = new FileInputStream("Keywords.txt");
    Scanner keywords = new Scanner(fileKeywords);
    keywords.useDelimiter("[^a-zA-Z']+");  // delimiters are nonletters,'

    FileInputStream fileJava = new FileInputStream(args[0]);
    Scanner java = new Scanner(fileJava); 
    java.useDelimiter("[^a-zA-Z']+");  // delimiters are nonletters,'

    while (java.hasNext()) {
      words1 = java.next();
      while (keywords.hasNext()) {
        words2 = keywords.next();
        if (words2.contains(words1)) {
          numWords++;
        }
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`words2` is **a single word**. `contains` here is the 'string contains' code. For example, `"Hello".contains("ell")` is true. Your intent is that `words2` is **all** keywords, but.. it isn't.

That while loop? Just delete it and start over:

- First, read *ALL* keywords (yes, this involves one single non-nested while loop) and store them in a datatype that is good at this. `HashSet` seems best, but if that scares you, `ArrayList` will do the job allright if the keywords list is less than ~1000 or so words.
- Then loop, once, through your 'second scanner', the one scanning the input file, (`java` seems like a really, really bad name for this - variable names are very important). Make sure the `contains` call you invoke is on some collection type (ArrayList or HashSet), not on a string.

Comment: The first part about the words and contains was really helpful, thank you for that :) i'll go ahead and retry it like you said, thank you for the help!